# ClassCastException when reading OUT parameters from EclipseLink PLSQLStoredProcedureCall

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, eclipselink

I need to call an Oracle Stored Procedure using EclipseLink (2.3.1.v20111018-r10243). The procedure have IN and OUT parameters, and I need to read the OUT parameter.

I found [this example](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/nonJDBCArgsToStoredProcedures) and my code is pretty much a copy of the example, but instead of receiving a List from the API, it is throwing an Exception because the value is an Integer of value "1", and I can't figure out why.

The procedure is being called properly, the IN parameter is ok, but the code fails to read the response which "should" be a List according to the example.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.JpaEntityManager;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.jdbc.JDBCTypes;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.plsql.OraclePLSQLTypes;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.plsql.PLSQLStoredProcedureCall;
import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatabaseRecord;
import org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.Session;

public class ProcedureCall {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public String execute(Long parameter) throws Exception {

        PLSQLStoredProcedureCall call = new PLSQLStoredProcedureCall();

        call.setProcedureName("two_arg_in_out");
        call.addNamedOutputArgument("X", OraclePLSQLTypes.BinaryInteger);
        call.addNamedArgument("Y", JDBCTypes.VARCHAR_TYPE, 40);

        DataModifyQuery query = new DataModifyQuery();
        query.setCall(call);
        query.addArgument("Y");

        List queryArgs = new ArrayList();
        queryArgs.add(parameter);

        Session session = ((JpaEntityManager) em.getDelegate()).getActiveSession();
        Object obj = session.executeQuery(query, queryArgs);

        // The system prints "Return: 1"
        System.out.println("Return: " + obj);

        List results = (List) obj; // Here is where exception happens

        DatabaseRecord record = (DatabaseRecord) results.get(0);
        String y = (String) record.get("X");

        return "done";
    }

}
```

The system throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

This is the procedure from the example I am using:

```
PROCEDURE two_arg_in_out(x OUT BINARY_INTEGER, y IN VARCHAR) AS
BEGIN
 x := 33;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks similar to the example shown here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/nonJDBCArgsToStoredProcedures#Handling_IN_and_OUT_arguments

The difference is you are using a DataModifyQuery which is designed around JDBC's executeUpdate to execute the query, and so returns an int instead of a resultset.  You will want to use a DataReadQuery to obtain results.

Comment: That is correct my friend. Not sure how I ended up using the wrong type.